# Как по очереди с задержкой добавить класс ко всем одноименным блокам?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Раньше писал скрипт для каждого блока вручную, но понял, что это вообще не вариант когда их больше 20, да и код громоздкий становится, как можно перебрать все блоки автоматически?

Ставить флаг и перебирать, пока количество элементов не привысит указанное тоже не вариант, потому что количество может меняться. Может быть есть какой то универсальный метод?

пробовал написать скрипт самостоятельно но не получилось, внизу привел пример:

```js
 $(".views-row").each(function(i) {

   $(this).eq(i).delay(800).addClass("active");
 });
```

```css
.views-row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.views-row.active {
  background: #65bb5c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
```

Если нет такого способа, то покажите хоть как перебрать с помощью флага, чтобы добавлял по очереди класс пока не превысит количество блоков.

Comment: А что `$(".views-row").delay(800).addClass("active");` не работает? Или не то делает?

Comment: как видите не перебирает, а добавляет класс только к первому а дальше не идет...

Comment: да и как я успел заметить задержки тоже нет.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, не перебирает потому что `eq(i)` лишнеее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $.each($('.views-row'), function(i, el) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(el).addClass("active");
    }, 500 + (i * 500));

  });
});
```

```css
.views-row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.views-row.active {
  background: #65bb5c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
```

Comment: это хорошо, но почему delay задерживает, например, hide и не задерживает addClass ?

Comment: delay только для функций анимации

Comment: самый понятный на данный момент вариант для меня. А можно было чторую строку заменить на вот это `$(".views-row").each(function(i, el) {`?? и что происходит тут `}, 500 + (i * 500));`??

Comment: результат `500 + (i * 500)` = 500, 1000, 1500 и тд

Answer (score 4):

С использованием promises

```js
$(".views-row").toArray().reduce(
  function(acc, cur) {
    return acc.then(function() {
      return $(cur).delay(800).promise().then(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active")
      });
    })
  }, Promise.resolve());
```

```css
.views-row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.views-row.active {
  background: #65bb5c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
```

Comment: модно, спортивно, молодежно :)))

Comment: и с использованием других непонятных слов) поизучаю на досуге, но за основу пока такой вариант не буду брать пока не переварю)

Answer (score 3):

Посоветую применить `setInterval()`

А после окончания убивать его...

```js
var setTheInterval = null;
setTheInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if ($(".views-row:not(.active)").length) {
    $(".views-row:not(.active)").eq(0).addClass('active');
  } else {
    clearInterval(setTheInterval);
  }
}, 800);
```

```css
.views-row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.views-row.active {
  background: #65bb5c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
<div class="views-row"></div>
```

Comment: Процесс не останавливается после перебора всех дивов.

Comment: ответ изменен. Если больше `.views-row:not(.active)` не найдено - убиваем интервал

Comment: @cyadvert, мож тогда результат селектора сохранить чтобы два раза не вызывать?